# Best command in Linux to match data then print certain data

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am looking to read the /etc/shadow file and strip out anything in the 2nd field that equal * or ! and anything in the 5th field not equal to 90 and then print out the 1st field, 5th field and 6th field and add the hostname at the end of each line and output it to a file. I am not sure what my best option is here....

example of /etc/shadow file

```
foo:$6$91s00atqlok0b861$7IJdhycBWBwipe82y6kaoXnAbwqhJNPyxXIiWzCFpb0um2aEquBKIaH5OAlGRAeua2F6jk6qQiicpC21aiTvt.:12345:7:90:7:30::
foofoo:!!:123456:0:90:7:::   
foofoofoo:$6$5WSZ.Gde$RGkaObncaycypz9.wnerXauAPyIqyDQzh9cyUPuZ4LiNfRDGIS5DasngA5x51HPczH9NsE8mvkClIOs7a1K3p0:1234:0:99999:7:::
```

output

```
foofoofoo, 99999, 7, hostname
```

`Field1=username

Field2=password

Field5=# days p/w needs to be changed

Field6=# of days to warn`

much thanks

Comment: `awk` is your friend.

Comment: awk definitely. Just update your question with example `/etc/shadow` and expected output.

Comment: read more at the [tag:awk] tag info page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: @JamesBrown sorry I added the examples. Thanks

Comment: Reading that requirement fries my brain. And where does that `90` come from as it is not in the same record as `foofoofoo`?

Comment: @JamesBrown sorry I am new to posting here and the formatting. I have added what the fields are I am concerned with and actually corrected the fields I wanted, my mistake. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question correctly this is something you are looking for:

```
awk -v hostname=$(hostname) -F: '{ if ($2 != "*" && $2 != "!" && $5 == "90") { printf("%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $5, $6, hostname)}}' /etc/shadow >output
```

Comment: nothing outputted from that. I added more details in my posting for what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: ok this is perfect just wanted I needed. Thanks so much @sergeynik

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you can do it in bash as well:

```
IFS=:
cat  /etc/shadow |
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 ; do
     echo -n "$f1, $f5, $f6, "
     hostname
done
```